# unable to open the admin link

Tags: magento-1.9.2.1

i patched ver1.9.2.1 with the latest version by downloading from the prepatched files from https://magecomp.com/blog/how-to-install-supee-7405-with-or-without-ssh/#SUPEE7405withoutSSH

after patching I am unable to open the backend link it gives the error
Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Core_Helper_UnserializeArray' not found in /mydomain.com/app/Mage.php on line 547

I not so familiar with magento patching. could anyone help me with step by step solution

Comment: Did you enable the Magento compiler?

Answer (score 0):

You should to go to app/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php then look for some code like this $links = []; and change to $links = array();
for me it is at line 124. Or you can search inside Sales.php file using ctrl+f command , and try to search for [] then change to array(). Hope it helps you. Thanks!!